Creating a .a static library using C#/dotnet
I would like to use some of my C# code in an XCode project by compiling my .net 9 class library into a static .a library (using NativeAOT and everything that is required).
I have researched quite a bit and tried some experimenting, but I couldn't get the compiler to create a .a file.
Is there some guidance or something I'm missing?

https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/main/core/nativeaot/NativeLibrary/README.md#building-static-libraries

Thank you! Do you know if the same .a library works for both iOS and MacOS or do I need 2 specific versions?

If both are in arm64 architecture, you only need one.
